# Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe to Excel | second Index as column name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sample Data frame :

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Apple'],
                                  ['OS', 'Web']],
                                 names=['Brand', 'Metric'])
col = ['Count']

df = pd.DataFrame(10, idx, col)
df
```

the data looks like this

[image]

When I download it as csv then it download like

```
df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

[image]

My Requirement is to download this data as pivot table, I am not able to find any way to move the second index as column name,  the desired output of data looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need write reshaped `DataFrame` by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with some data cleaning to `csv`:

```
df['Count'].unstack().rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1).to_csv('example.csv')
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Count'].unstack().rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1))
           OS  Web
Apple      10   10
Google     10   10
Microsoft  10   10
```